# 2-d Linked List copy constructor using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to make a 2-d singly linked list where each node has a right pointer and a below pointer.  I've had a lot of troubles implementing the copy constructor since I am pretty sure recursion is the way to go, and I am pretty bad at recursion.  Do I need to change anything that you see, or does it look ok?

Here is the declaration in the header:

```
typedef int elementType;
struct node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
struct node
{
    elementType elt;
    nodePtr right = NULL;
    nodePtr below = NULL;
};

class LinkedList
{
protected:
    nodePtr head, tail;
    int size;
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &list); // copy constructor

    void recursiveCreate(nodePtr ptr);
}
```

This is in my cpp file

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList &list)
{
    nodePtr current = NULL;

    if (list.head == 0)
        head == 0;

    else
    {
        current = list.head;
        recursiveCreate(current);       
    }
}

void LinkedList::recursiveCreate(nodePtr ptr)
{
    nodePtr n = new node; //create new node
    n->elt = ptr->elt;      //copy value into that new node
    n->right = ptr->right;  //move right n pointer
    n->below = n->below;    //move right below pointer
    recursiveCreate(ptr->right);  //call on right node
    recursiveCreate(ptr->below);  //call on below node
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The up front big thing: This is a binary tree, not a linked list. Calling it a linked list just leads to confusion.

On topic, recursion is not the way to go for a linked list. For a tree it could be. But what you have does not work for a couple reasons.

1) There is no terminating condition. The recursion will plow into a NULL pointer and do bad things. First off in `recursiveCreate` you want to exit if `nodePtr` is NULL.

2) You're setting the current node to point at the wrong stuff. For example,

```
n->right = ptr->right;
```

has the node pointing at a node in the wrong list. That's an almost certain bad end. You want to point at the node created by `recursiveCreate`.

Let's take a look at what this would have to look like:

```
nodePtr LinkedList::recursiveCreate(nodePtr ptr)
{
    if (ptr == nullptr) 
    {
        return nullptr; // source tree stops here
    }
    nodePtr n = new node; //create new node
    n->elt = ptr->elt;      //copy value into that new node
    n->right = recursiveCreate(ptr->right);  //call on right node
    n->below = recursiveCreate(ptr->below);  //call on below node
    return n;
}
```

and

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList &list)
{
    nodePtr current = nullptr;

    if (list.head == nullptr) // NAG!!! For Crom's sake! 0 is not a pointer!
        head == nullptr;      // Use nullptr and get type checking working for you.

    else
    {
        head = recursiveCreate(list.head);       
    }
}
```

Special bonus operator

```
LinkedList & operator=(LinkedList list) // pass by reference. Copy constructor copies 
                                        // for you
{
    std::swap(head, list.head); // steal head from copy and give copy the empty   
    return *this; // all done.
}
```